# dev file for microphone

Tags: audio, radio

On my pi, I want to use my microphone in the terminal, as if it were a sound file. If it is not clear what I want to do, I am trying to broadcast sound as an fm radio signal. The command that I use looks like this:

```
sudo ./fm_transmitter -f frequency -r filename
```

Were it says "filename" I want the microphone to be specified. Is there any were to do this?

Comment: Are you using [this library](https://github.com/markondej/fm_transmitter) for your transmitter?

Comment: @goobering Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Github page](https://github.com/markondej/fm_transmitter) for the library you're using includes an example on how to pipe audio from a USB sound card (you don't indicate in your question what interface you're using) into the FM application:

> **USB sound-card**
>
> To use a USB sound-card type this:
>
> ```
> arecord -D hw:1,0 -c1 -d 0 -r 22050 -f S16_LE | sudo ./fm_transmitter -f 100.6 -
> ```
>
> Some devices have problems with this command (there is a warning in
>   the terminal like buffer overflow and after a few seconds - the
>   transmitting gets slow and will stop), then you can use the following:
>
> ```
> arecord -D plughw:1,0 -c1 -d 0 -r 22050 -f S16_LE | sudo ./fm_transmitter -f 100.6 -
> ```